# Display default text inside a p tag if there is no value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a content editable `<p>` and an input of type submit. So, if there is no value inside the `<p>`, I want to display a default text (eg. "Add comment..."). If contenteditable is in focus remove the default text. Now if contenteditable is not in focus and user has input some text, leave the user typed text. However, if contenteditable is not in focus and theres not value display the default text. How can I do this in css or javascript (no jquery) ?

```css
#add_comment {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 720px;
    margin: 1px auto;
    background: white;
}

#divLeft {
    vertical-align: top;
    display:table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}

#add_comment #comment {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    outline: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

#divRight {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 120px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#divRight #submit {
    background: #2ec76e;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="add_comment">
  <div id="divLeft">
    <p id="comment" contenteditable="true"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="divRight">
    <input type="submit" value="Comment" id="submit" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you have a `p` element instead of an `input` one? In the latter case, you could use `placeholder="Add comment..."`, which would already provide the functionality you're looking for, plus allow for individual styling, while working without JS-enabled browsers.

Comment: @TheThirdMan So that when I add more content, it will increase its height.

Comment: Ah, I can see that reasoning... you should note, however, that this will make it difficult for screen readers or automating tools to analyze what's going on on your page, so don't try this for anything that cares about accessibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps with the `:empty` pseudo-class and a pseudo-element?

```css
#add_comment {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 720px;
  margin: 1px auto;
  background: white;
}
#divLeft {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
}
#add_comment #comment {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
#divRight {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 120px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#divRight #submit {
  background: #2ec76e;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
p:empty:before {
  content: 'Add Comment';
  color: grey
}
p:focus::before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="add_comment">
  <div id="divLeft">
    <p id="comment" contenteditable="true"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="divRight">
    <input type="submit" value="Comment" id="submit" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow.. is it cross browser?

Answer (score 0):

Just put a control inside the p tag like this:

`<p> <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></p>`

or you can use html input tag.

Comment: <p><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></p>

Comment: Apologies on my part.. it think it system error.. i include that answer on the answer above at the center of the two sentences but when i proceed. the answer left behind. Im just a new member. Apologies

Comment: Edited it for you.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/jcma31L8/

```
$(function(){

$dfText = 'How was your day hum?'
$p = $('p');

$p.text($dfText);

$('input').on('input',function(){
    $text = $(this).val();
    if( $text == '' ){
    $p.text($dfText)
  }else{
    $p.text($text)
  }

});


});
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could do something like this

**jQuery**

```
var placeHolder = 'Add Comment';

$("#comment").text(placeHolder);

$("#comment").bind("focusin blur", function () {
  if ($(this).text() === placeHolder) {
    $(this).text('');
  } else if($(this).text() === ''){
    $("#comment").text(placeHolder);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
 p:empty:not(:focus)::before 
 {
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
 }

 <p data-placeholder="Insert text here..." contenteditable></p>
```